# Pythonic way to create pairs of values in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` that looks like this:

```
OwnerID    Value
1            A
1            B
1            C
1            D
```

This is the shortened version, I have thousands of values for `OwnerID`. I'd like to create pairs for the `Value` column where each `Value` is paired with every other `Value`, and have the result as list of pairs.

For example, for the `OwnerID` 1, the resultset should be the following lists:

```
[A,B]

[A,C]

[A,D]

[B,C]

[B,D]

[C,D]
```

I could write 2 `for` loops to achieve this, but that wouldn't be very efficient or pythonic. Would someone know a better way to achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @B.Eckles yeah, just noticed that. My bad.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin lol I just noticed you noticed that. ;D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools as iter
df2 = df.groupby('OwnerID').Value.apply(lambda x: list(iter.combinations(x, 2)))
```

will return the desired output for each unique owner id

```
OwnerID
1    [(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)]
```

Comment: @Patthebug, i just edited the answer to take care of each unique owner id

Comment: Very nice solution !

Answer (score 6):

Pandas solution (using [.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) methods):

Data:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   OwnerID Value
0        1     A
1        1     B
2        1     C
3        1     D
4        2     X
5        2     Y
6        2     Z
```

Solution:

```
In [9]: pd.merge(df, df, on='OwnerID', suffixes=['','2']).query("Value != Value2")
Out[9]:
    OwnerID Value Value2
1         1     A      B
2         1     A      C
3         1     A      D
4         1     B      A
6         1     B      C
7         1     B      D
8         1     C      A
9         1     C      B
11        1     C      D
12        1     D      A
13        1     D      B
14        1     D      C
17        2     X      Y
18        2     X      Z
19        2     Y      X
21        2     Y      Z
22        2     Z      X
23        2     Z      Y
```

If you need only lists:

```
In [17]: pd.merge(df, df, on='OwnerID', suffixes=['','2']) \
           .query("Value != Value2") \
           .filter(like='Value').values
Out[17]:
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C'],
       ['A', 'D'],
       ['B', 'A'],
       ['B', 'C'],
       ['B', 'D'],
       ['C', 'A'],
       ['C', 'B'],
       ['C', 'D'],
       ['D', 'A'],
       ['D', 'B'],
       ['D', 'C'],
       ['X', 'Y'],
       ['X', 'Z'],
       ['Y', 'X'],
       ['Y', 'Z'],
       ['Z', 'X'],
       ['Z', 'Y']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: .query is provided by pandas? Can't believe I missed such an awesome method!

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is all you need.

Depending on how you want to combine them, try either [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) or [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), for example.

Answer (score 0):

try itertools

```
import itertools

list(itertools.combinations(['a','b','c','d'], 2))

#result: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = df['Value'].values
length = len(val)
pairs = [[val[i],val[j]] for i in xrange(length) for j in xrange(length) if i!=j]
```